# How to replace nested loops with Java 8 streams

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I want to use Java 8 stream for the below implementation. Basically i want to parse one list and form another list of different objects.

**Input** - list of Person pojos, 
**Output** - list of PersonInfo pojos

```
    List<Person> persons = new ArrayList<Person>();

    Person max = new Person();
    max.setName("Max");
    max.setAge(10);
    max.addAddress(new Address("Street1", "City1"));
    max.addAddress(new Address("Street2", "City2"));

    Person peter = new Person();
    peter.setName("Peter");
    peter.setAge(20);
    peter.addAddress(new Address("Street1", "City1"));
    peter.addAddress(new Address("Street2", "City2"));

    persons.add(max);
    persons.add(peter);

    System.out.println("Input: " + persons);

    List<PersonInfo> personInfos = new ArrayList<PersonInfo>();
    PersonInfo personInfo = null;
    for (Person person : persons) {
        for (Address addr : person.getCurrAndPrevAddrs()) {
            personInfo = new PersonInfo();
            personInfo.setName(person.getName());
            personInfo.setAge(person.getAge());
            personInfo.setAddrs(addr);              
            personInfos.add(personInfo);
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Output: " + personInfos.toString());
```

**sample output**:
**Input**: [Max 10  [Street1    City1, Street2  City2]

, Peter 20  [Street1    City1, Street2  City2]]

**Output**: [Max    10  Street1 City1

, Max   10  Street2 City2

, Peter 20  Street1 City1

, Peter 20  Street2 City2]

Comment: output: Input: ??

Comment: @Elise van Looij, i have provided the sample output and input on my question _at the end_. Please let me know if you need additional information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
List<PersonInfo> personInfos = persons.stream().flatMap(person -> person.getCurrAndPrevAddrs().stream().map(addr -> {
        PersonInfo personInfo = new PersonInfo();
        personInfo.setName(person.getName());
        personInfo.setAge(person.getAge());
        personInfo.setAddrs(addr);              
        return personInfo;
})).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: I'm getting some compilation errors. 1. `persons.flatMap`, 'persons' is list or stream, i think you mean to say `persons.stream().flatMap` 2. 'Type mismatch: cannot convert from Stream<Object> to List<PersonInfo>'

Comment: @Pons I'm on my phone, so it's hard for me to verify. Can you be more specific?

Comment: @Pons You're right on the first point. I also missed a parenthesis. Try now.

Comment: `p.getCurrAndPrevAddrs()` should be `person.getCurrAndPrevAddrs()`, right?

Comment: it is working fine now. Thanks. Do you have any suggestion on moving the below code `PersonInfo personInfo = new PersonInfo();
        personInfo.setName(person.getName());
        personInfo.setAge(person.getAge());
        personInfo.setAddrs(addr);              
        return personInfo;` to 'PersonInfo' class to simplify this nested stream statement.

Comment: @Pons I'd use a constructor instead of the setters so the lambda can be reduced to `person -> new PersonInfo(person.getName(), person.getAge(), addr)`, or maybe even `person -> new PersonInfo(person, addr)`.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simplified version of what you're trying to do. I simplified the Pojos for my testing.

```
List<Person> persons = new ArrayList<Person>();

Person person1 = new Person("person1");
Person person2 = new Person("person2");

persons.add(person1);
persons.add(person2);

List<PersonInfo> personInfos = new ArrayList<PersonInfo>();
persons.stream().forEach(person -> {    
  person.getCurrAndPrevAddrs().stream().forEach(address -> {
    PersonInfo personInfo = new PersonInfo("personInfo");
    personInfo.setAddress(address);
    personInfos.add(personInfo);
  });
});

System.out.println("Output: " + personInfos.toString());
```

Comment: thanks, this is working fine. But the one thing is, the `forEach` is available for `Iterable`, so, I'm trying to get my head around, what advantages this will give me?

Comment: This looks like it will throw a `ConcurrentModificationException` on parallel implementations.

Answer (score 1):

One way to (1) improve readability and (2) simplify maintenance of your code is to add a `toPersonInfo` method to your `Person` class, like so:

```
public class Person {
    //getters, setters, etc.
    public List<PersonInfo> toPersonInfos() {
        List<PersonInfo> result = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Address addr : getCurrentAndPrevAddrs()) {
            PersonInfo pi = new PersonInfo();
            pi.setName(this::getName);
            pi.setAge(this::getAge);
            pi.setAddrs(this::addr);
            result.add(pi);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

That way, if you ever change your `PersonInfo` or your `Person` class, you only have to change one method, and it's right there in your `Person` class.

It also greatly simplifies the stream operation:

```
personInfos = persons.stream().flatMap(p -> p.toPersonInfos.stream()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Note that this will not necessarily return an ordered list.

Answer (score -1):

A cleaner and elegant way to do this could be :

```
 List<PersonInfo> personInfos = persons.stream()
                .map(person -> person.getCurrAndPrevAddrs())
                .flatMap(List::stream)
                .map(this::createPersonInfo)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

 private PersonInfo createPersonInfo() {
        PersonInfo personInfo = new PersonInfo();
        personInfo.setName(person.getName());
        personInfo.setAge(person.getAge());
        personInfo.setAddrs(addr);
        return personInfo;
    }
```